# How to calculate timings of short sell or buy long?

Tags: stock, cryptocurrency, candlestick-chart, forex

I have seen on YouTube. Some people calculate the timings when to take short or long of crypto, forex, etc. For example, I have seen in a live session that the host says, we will take short at 3:41 (for example, btc, euro, eth, etc). How do they calculate these timings?

I have tried to search it on internet with different keywords. Even I have been searching for this about a year. But there is no material I found on the internet.